# MsgBox should show up on top of a Selenium Webdriver Chrome Window

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Basically I have this little MsgBox that pops up and asks for a Yes / No question, and I'd like to know if it's possible to have it show up on its own over a chrome driver window (so without the VBA / Excel window behind it). Maybe there's a way to just hide the main Excel / VBA Window?

This is the MsgBox I have right now.

```
answer = MsgBox("Text", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbApplicationModal, "Message Box Title")
If answer = vbYes Then
Sheet4.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = bot.url
answer = ""
End If
If bot.Windows.count > 1 Then
bot.Close
bot.Windows.Last.Activate
End If
Loop Until bot.Windows.count = 1
```

I do realize this may be impossible but I'd appreciate any pointers!
Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.visible

Comment: Maybe look into using a different msgbox type: https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-popup.html   Not sure what effect that might have on application focus though...

Comment: Only a program whose windows is in the foreground can set the forground window.